# Show that $f$ is a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis

In order to correctly solve an exercise where I have to calculate the conjugate of the following function $f$, I have to be able to show that it is a convex function.

$$f : \{(x,t) : \| x \| < t\} \subset\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad (x,t) \mapsto-\log(t^2 - x'x)$$

I tried to show that the Hessian is positive in the sense of symmetrical matrices (unsuccessful). I also tried the following decomposition:

$$f(x,t) = -\log(\vert t \vert - \| x \|) - \log(\vert t \vert + \| x \|))$$

But I don't see how to conclude from this decomposition. I can't apply a composition rule that would preserve convexity, nor can I make the perspective function of a convex function appear.

Any hint?

Comment: Can you write "définie sur" in English? I am not aware of what that means.

Comment: Sorry yes I edited it

Comment: Could you show us your attempt via the Hessian? That should be straightforward.

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hessian+matrix+of+-log%28+y%5E2+-+x%5E2+%29) is interesting.